# Redis master and slave use different memory

Tags: replication, redis

I deployed a redis replica set which consist of one master and one slave.

From `top` command output, I figure out each memory usage.

master: 8176352Byte * 8.5% = 678MB

slave: 2050116Byte * 75.6% = 1513MB

Why does slave use much more memory than master?

master `top` output:

```
...
KiB Mem:   8176352 total,  7746300 used,   430052 free,    55048 buffers
KiB Swap:  8385892 total,  2360512 used,  6025380 free.  1279644 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
32609 redis     20   0 1717424 696708    928 S   0.3  8.5 304:22.75 redis-server
...
```

slave `top` output:

```
...
KiB Mem:   2050116 total,  1977052 used,    73064 free,     3620 buffers
KiB Swap:  2096444 total,   259100 used,  1837344 free.   165552 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND      
 1675 redis     20   0 1725616 1.477g    672 S  0.0 75.6   0:23.03 redis-server
 ...
```

Answer (score -1):

```
MASTER_HOST="master_host"
MASTER_PORT="6379"
SLAVE_HOST="slave_host"
SLAVE_PORT="6379"

# Function to gather Redis information
gather_redis_info() {
    HOST=$1
    PORT=$2
    INFO=$(redis-cli -h $HOST -p $PORT info)
    echo "$INFO"
}

# Function to compare memory usage between master and slave
compare_memory_usage() {
    MASTER_INFO=$(gather_redis_info $MASTER_HOST $MASTER_PORT)
    SLAVE_INFO=$(gather_redis_info $SLAVE_HOST $SLAVE_PORT)

    MASTER_MEMORY=$(echo "$MASTER_INFO" | grep "used_memory:" | awk -F: '{print $2}')
    SLAVE_MEMORY=$(echo "$SLAVE_INFO" | grep "used_memory:" | awk -F: '{print $2}')

    echo "Master Memory Usage: $MASTER_MEMORY bytes"
    echo "Slave Memory Usage: $SLAVE_MEMORY bytes"

    if [ "$MASTER_MEMORY" -eq "$SLAVE_MEMORY" ]; then
        echo "Memory usages are the same."
    else
        echo "Memory usages are different. Investigate further."
    fi
}
```